# Generating an uncomputable number by throwing dice

Tags: computability

If I were to roll a die infinitely many times, assuming the result was truly random, and use the results as the decimal places of a number, would that number (likely) be an uncomputable number?

Comment: If you have a countable number of computable numbers then ...

Comment: By Borel-Cantelli it should be transcendental

Comment: @maxjw91 Yes, but some transcendenttal numbers are computable. Also, Borel-Cantelli is overkill here.

Comment: If you determine the digits actually randomly , the probability is $1$ that you will get an uncomputable number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. There are only countably many computable numbers (because there are only countably many computer programs), so a random real number, say in the interval $[0, 1]$ to be concrete, is uncomputable with probability $1$.

In fact with probability $1$ it will have a much stronger property called [algorithmic randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence), which roughly speaking says that the digits are incompressible.

Comment: The real lesson here is that "assuming that the digits are truly random" is an extremely strong assumption. In practice it's unclear how you could ever come to believe this...

Comment: Hilariously (to my mind) probably the most practical way to ascertain "randomness" is, as you say, to appraise compressibility... but _actual_ Kolmogorov-etal complexity is not computable, either... so just run a few of the standard compression algorithms and see what happens? :)